# How to create a shortcut using wix that could change depending on a user's system

Tags: c#, wix, shortcut

I have created a Wix installer that places 3 shortcuts onto the desktop. One of these shortcuts references the user's DVD Drive. Is there a way to dynamically set the target of this shortcut based on that drive letter? Would a custom action be the way to go? If so how would I change the target of a shortcut using that custom action. I have been writing my custom actions in C# and would hope to continue doing so.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the target of a shortcut with the value of a property. For example, the following will take the value of the `MYSTUFF` property as the target:

```
<Shortcut Id="MyStuffShortcut" Name='My Stuff' Target="[MYSTUFF]" />
```

There is no [standard windows installer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905(VS.85).aspx) for "the DVD drive". I'm not sure what that would even mean if there were multiple DVD drives. You can use [`ROOTDRIVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371372(VS.85).aspx) to refer to the local drive with the most free space. You can use [`SourceDir`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371857(VS.85).aspx) to refer to the root of the drive where the installer is being executed from.

Comment: The problem is that unfortunately your right about how dynamic it would have to be to achieve this. What i have ended up doing is creating a custom action to create the link that runs after my install so the user can select the drive and it generates it from there. Thanks for the response.